# Infinite loop in Python cannot stop

Tags: python, loops

I tried to do a loop but this keeps giving me an infinite loop can anyone help me ?

```
difficulty = int (input ( '"1" for Easy \n"2" for Medium \n"3" for Hard\n'))

while difficulty <= 0 or difficulty >= 4 :
  print ('Invalid Choice. Try Again!')
```

Comment: What happens `difficulty` is "invalid"? You need to re-input so its value can change.

Comment: put `if` instead of `while`, if you are trying something to do

Comment: Try to read [this](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex33.html) first

Comment: You're not giving a way to update `difficulty` in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing while the difficulty is within a range. The only problem is that the difficulty variable is only set once, before the loop. Try moving it inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use chaining of operators and get the input again

```
while not 0 < difficulty < 4:
    print('Invalid Choice. Try Again!')
    difficulty = int(input('"1" for Easy \n"2" for Medium \n"3" for Hard\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to choose the difficulty, if it's ok then you don't getting inside the loop, if the value is not good, then you are inside the while until you will choose a proper value for difficulty.

**Edit:**

I added for you a function called safe_input, that way you can manage when the user inputs string or bad characters. I made it generic as you can define the text and the expected type of the user_input.

```
def safe_input(text, instance):
    user_input = raw_input(text)
    try:
        return instance(user_input)
    except:
        return False

def choose_difficulty():
    return safe_input(text= '"1" for Easy \n"2" for Medium \n"3" for Hard\n', instance=int)

difficulty = choose_difficulty()
while difficulty <= 0 or difficulty >= 4:
    print ('Invalid Choice. Try Again!')
    difficulty = choose_difficulty()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is more like what you are trying to acheive:

```
while True:
    difficulty = int (input ( '"1" for Easy \n"2" for Medium \n"3" for Hard\n'))

    if 0 < difficulty < 4:
        break

    print('Invalid Choice. Try Again!')
```

The while loop needs to include both your `input` line and the `print` statement inside it. The `break` statement is used to exit from the loop (and continue running after the loop) when a correct value is entered.